# EXCEL SumIf with multiple conditions from another cell/array

Tags: excel

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User | Task | Hours |
| 2 | Jim | AA-1 | 10 |
| 3 | Mike | AA-2 | 12 |
| 4 | Jim | AA-3 | 13 |
| 5 | Steve | CC-5 | 14 |
| 6 | Jim | BB-1 | 15 |
| 7 | Mike | BB-3 | 5 |
| 8 | Steve | BB-4 | 10 |
| 9 | Mike | CC-5 | 8 |

The table is way bigger and there are more than just AA, BB and CC type of tasks.

I want to be able to get how many hours Jim spent on tasks that start by AA* or BB*

This is simple with a sumifs but the problem is when I have 20 different type of tasks and I Want to get a lot of people results.

So I want to get in a row how many hours Jim spent on AA, BB and CC tasks and in the next row how many he spent on DD, EE, FF.

Basically I would like a sumif like (just look at the last part):

```
('SHEET1'!C:C,'SHEET1'!E:E,$B$3,'SHEET1'!G:G,"AA*,BB*,CC*")
```

Or even better if the AA*,BB*,CC* part were in another cell to easily change it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula-

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,$F3,$B$2:$B$9,G$2)
```

You may also use following formulas.

<kbd>**F3=**</kbd>`=UNIQUE(A2:A9)`
<kbd>**G2=**</kbd>`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(B2:B9,"-"))))&"*"`

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer but maybe I wasn't clear enough. G2 should have AA*, BB* and CC*. The main issue is that we have about 60 different type of tasks (AA*...) and we have to create different groups (product 1 contains tasks from AA, BB, CC, DD ...) so grouping products is hard. However just writing this I thought of a solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to Harun24hr answer I started to think in doing it in different steps.

As I stated above I have the following table:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | User | Task | Hours |
| 2 | Jim | AA-1 | 10 |
| 3 | Mike | AA-2 | 12 |
| 4 | Jim | AA-3 | 13 |
| 5 | Steve | CC-5 | 14 |
| 6 | Jim | BB-1 | 15 |
| 7 | Mike | BB-3 | 5 |
| 8 | Steve | BB-4 | 10 |
| 9 | Mike | CC-5 | 8 |

The issue is that I might have a lot of different type of tasks and I need to group some results, so I created another table to stablish the groups:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group | Task |
| 2 | a | AA* |
| 3 | a | BB* |
| 4 | b | CC* |
| 5 | a | DD* |

This new table is easier to maintain and I can then add a new column on the main table that represents the group based on this grouping table and then do the calculation with a simple sumif.

Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: In this post second table is your desired result?

Comment: So in this second table, with the column group I can then create a column D in the first table that represents which group each type of task belongs to and then I can do the sum based on the group.